How does guest watering work?
I don't get what 'unique visitor' means. Does it have to be like visitors from other islands or just different players from the same island / same system?
I had one of my family members create an extra two accounts to bring it up to three people watering but the sparkles haven't changed or look more rapid. they just look the same.
If anyone knows what counts in the game as 'unique visitor' that would be really helpful.

Okay, with some heavy testing, Can confirm. Guest watering doesn't have to be like three to five switch users interacting. It can be just two switches but the 'guest' one has to have multiple users / player villagers to come visit.
So if you can get someone with another switch and bit of free time each day to play three to more characters you can boost flower breeding just like all the YT flower guide videos say.
Hope this is helpful to someone.
